# Java: Using one Method for different types in the array parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I just cant't figure this out maybe you can help me.

The problem:

---

```
public class class1 implements Comparable<class1> {
    public int compareTo(class1 o) {
        //some code
    }
}

public class class2 implements Comparable<class2> {
    public int compareTo(class2 o) {
        //some code
    }
}

public class foo {
    private ArrayList<Class1> abc = new ArrayList<Class1>(); 
    private ArrayList<Class2> def = new ArrayList<Class2>();
}
```

In the following `o = abc or def`

```
public int foo1 (ArrayList<Object> o) {
   o[0].compareTo(o[1]);
}
```

This code keeps getting me this error:

```
The method compareTo(class1) is undefined for the type Object
```

I do understand why but I can't find a workarround so that I don't have to duplicate code, which would be necessary because I have more ArrayList objects and much longer code.

I hope one of you has an idea.

PROBLEM SOLVED!!! Solution was :

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int foo1 (ArrayList<T> o) {
  return o.get(0).compareTo(o.get(1));
}
```

by Peter Lawrey

Comment: If your question is answered, you should mark the right answer as "accepted" (there should be an "accept" button or such near it), then it gets a green √ icon, and Peter gets 15 more reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

`implements Comparable<class1>`

you are implementing so you need to provide implementation  for all the method of interface otherwise make it abstract

implement it like

```
public class class1 implements Comparable<class1> {

    public int compareTo(class1 o) {
       //some code
    }
}

public class class2 implements Comparable<class2> {

    public int compareTo(class2 o) {
       //some code
    }
}
```

- [Interface Doc](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you use an object by it's super class methods, you cannot assume that it's subclass methods are available.

Comment: Well yes i figured that too. any ides to workarround the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try the following which compiles and works for `abc` and `def` without warning.

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int foo1 (ArrayList<T> o) {
    return o.get(0).compareTo(o.get(1));
}
```

Comment: Tryed Does work but it still shows that i use raw types and i am not sure if this is okay.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked. I have one more question: I dont actually compare the array to itself but to a new object of the type that the objects in the array have. How do I get an object of the type of the array-objects in such a generic function. Thanks a heap

Comment: You can get the type, by either passing it as an argument or looking at the first element and assuming they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the method generic:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int foo1 (ArrayList<T> o) {
```

Comment: tried it and got this error:                     Syntax error on token "extends", , expected